# RegExp досадное поведение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

Сложились так обстоятельства, что вынужден я просить у Вас помощи.

**Есть адрес:**
http://site.com/profile/$username$/requests/

Собственно необходимо получить:

- Если после **username** стоит **requests**
- Если после **username** ничего нет

Далее это все пойдет в `routing`, поэтому необходимо $1 :)

Для второго, где нужно проверить, есть ли requests, получилось так:

```
$route['profile/(.*)/([requests]+)'] = "profile/requests/$1";
```

Буду рад помощи.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще тут хватит split(/\//), но если нужен регексп то как-то, например, так:

```
m|profile/(.+?)/?(.+)?$|
```

Comment: Спасибо вам.

Буду изучать.